# Path not showing in android canvas when passing exponential value for X, Y point

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-canvas

I am calculating pixel point dynamically to draw a polyline in xamarin.android OnDraw method. Sometimes i get X, Y value like **75311056**. If i convert this double to float value to draw line, it returns exponential value like **7.531106E+07**. When passing exponential value, line was not showing visually. I can't use double value directly in canvas.MoveTo() canvas.LineTo() method as method argument type is float. Refer the below code,

```
Path path = new Path();
for (int k = 0; k < shape.Points.Length; k++)
{
if (k == 0)
{
  double x = shape.Points[k][0] * Scale;
  double y = shape.Points[k][1] * Scale;      
  path.MoveTo((float)x, (float)y);
}
else
{
  double x = shape.Points[k][0] * Scale;
  double y = shape.Points[k][1] * Scale;
  path.LineTo((float)x, (float)y);
}
}

paint.Color = new Color(color);
paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
paint.StrokeWidth = 2;
canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
```

Guide me in resolving this problem. Is it framework side issue?

Comment: What is shape? Can you provide complete code to test?